# Create functions in preproccesor in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using a timer library in Arduino IDE that has a function which takes "void(*func)(void)" as a parameter and runs it after certain time.I need to pass a function in my code with that library, the problem is I need "n" functions that do the same thing (just the variables involved inside the function take different values, which I take from an array of struct), that's why I can't use only one function and I need to be able to compile different functions with identical syntax but different variables involved.

I don't know how I can resolve this, what I want to do is to be able to create functions like in a for loop,

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX_FUNC;i++)
{    
void func[i](){
x= structuredata.x[i];
}
}
```

I know this syntax is completely wrong but I'd like to know how can I achieve something like this . I tried using classes instead, but the library didn't let me use void functions created in a class as parameters, it indicated "unresolved overloaded function type"

Comment: Do you mean something like templates?

Comment: yes , I want to be able to create functions modifying just the name of the function and the array I want to access inside the function

Comment: I think you are asking how to copy paste functions, like `func1() { x = data.x[1]; }` and then `func2`, `func3`, and etc.. There has got to be a better way to go about solving your problem! For example just have your function take a `int i` and make the function `func(int i) { x = data.x[i]; }` Or something like this?

Comment: Most libraries that I've seen that take callbacks like that, also take an extra void* so that you can pass in arbitrary data to your function, so that you don't get into this situation. Are you sure your timer library doesn't provide that?

Comment: The library I'm using is https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer
and the function that I'm using for the callbacks is 
after(unsigned long period, void (*callback)())

Comment: Not taking the additional parameter is a sign of an outdated or bad design. Consider submitting a bug report/patch, forking the library and adding the parameter, or using another library.

Comment: Oh, and it's even a C++ library and not C. Pretty bad. I'd fork it without thinking twice. Possibly using templated functor ir std::function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're into template overrides and can restructure your functions as such, a solution to packing up a stack of callbacks to be fired consecutively is closer than you may think. You *can* make this more generic if the consistency of the function is literally identical. I.e. you can do this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int ar[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

// your function here
template <int i>
void callback()
{
    // your code here. i is provided
    int x = ar[i];
    std::cout << "Got Value: " <<  x << '\n';
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// unraveller
template<int N>
void callback_set()
{
    callback_set<N-1>();
    callback<N-1>();
}

// base callback set
template<>
void callback_set<0>() {}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    callback_set<3>();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Got Value: 1
Got Value: 2
Got Value: 3
```

You "register" `callback_set<N>` as your callback, and it will chain up the calls to your function(s) for you. If individualized access to *different* implementations is needed, you can still to that, using full specializations:

```
#include <iostream>

// prototypes
template <int i>
void callback() {};

// your functions here
template<>
void callback<0>()
{
    std::cout << "Callback #0" << '\n';
}

template<>
void callback<1>()
{
    std::cout << "Callback #1" << '\n';
}

template<>
void callback<2>()
{
    std::cout << "Callback #2" << '\n';
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// unraveller
template<int N>
void callback_set()
{
    callback_set<N-1>();
    callback<N-1>();
}

// base callback set
template<>
void callback_set<0>() {}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    callback_set<3>();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Callback #0
Callback #1
Callback #2
```

In essence you style-up your registered callback using `callback_set<N>` where `N` is the number of callbacks you've provided overrides for. Just a thought, but seems like it would be a fairly elegant solution to your problem if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need some metaprogramming for that...

```
const int MAX_FUNC = 1000;

typedef void (*Tcallback)();
struct Tdata
{
    int whatever;
};

Tdata callbackData[MAX_FUNC];
Tcallback callbacks[MAX_FUNC];

template <int index>
void callbackToIndex()
{
//  callback knows it's index and thus can access some global structure for it's data
    printf("%u", index);
    callbackData[index];
}

template <int index>
void callbackCreate()
{
    callbacks[index] = &callbackToIndex<index>;
    callbackCreate<index - 1>();
}
template <>
void callbackCreate<-1>()
{
}

void create()
{
    callbackCreate<MAX_FUNC - 1>();
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote: You may be better off creating your own scheduler (that is registering only one timer with Arduiono, and in callback calling first scheduled function and then registering next scheduled function....)